# how to send Java object into between two mxml files in java?

Tags: java, apache-flex, mxml

I'm Using Flex + java .. in that i have two Sub mxml files Sub1.mxml and Sub2.mxml

Sub1.mxml code..

```
[Bindable] private var editTimetableVO:TimetableVO;
        public function forwardToCreateEvent(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            editTimetableVO = new TimetableVO();
editTimetableVO=editDataGrid.selectedItem as TimetableVO;//editDataGrid is DataGrid id
                Alert.show("value   "+editTimetableVO.startDate);
            }
```

Hear Alert is Print some date it is good... then my Second Mxml file..

Sub2.mxml code..

```
public var myEditEvent:Sub1 = new Sub1();
private var timetableVO:TimetableVO = new TimetableVO();

    //  private var editTimetableVO:TimetableVO = new TimetableVO();
        protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            Alert.show("Show");
            timetableVO=myEditEvent.editDataGrid.selectedItem as TimetableVO;

            Alert.show("value "+timetableVO.startDate);

        }
```

But in that time Alert not Printing ....
Is their any other way to access to `editTimetableVO` in Sub1.mxml to Sub2.mxml file...

Comment: This is an MXML file and you're creating a new instance of Sub1 through ActionScript. Why is that? I'm asking because it's probably the root of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
package
{
public class ModelLocator{
    public static var instance:ModelLocator;

    public var editTimetableVO:*;

    public function ModelLocator(instance:SingletonEnforcer){}

    public static function getInstance():ModelLocator{
        if(!instance){
            instance = new ModelLocator(new SingletonEnforcer());
        }
        return instance;
    }
}

}class SingletonEnforcer{}

// sub1.mxml
[Bindable]private var model:ModelLocator = ModelLocator.getInstance();
    public function forwardToCreateEvent(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        model.editTimetableVO = new TimetableVO();
        model.editTimetableVO=editDataGrid.selectedItem as     TimetableVO;//editDataGrid is DataGrid id
        Alert.show("value   "+model.editTimetableVO.startDate);
        }


// Sub2.mxml
[Bindable]private var model:ModelLocator = ModelLocator.getInstance();
    protected function init(event:FlexEvent):void
    {
        Alert.show("Show");
        model.timetableVO=myEditEvent.editDataGrid.selectedItem as TimetableVO;

        Alert.show("value "+model.timetableVO.startDate);

    }
```

Comment: downvote as you could edit your original answer with the code rather then writing a new answer.

Comment: ModelLocator giving error:  
"A file found in a source-path can not have more than one externally visible definition. ModelLocator;SingletonEnforcer ModelLocator.as"

Comment: Thankyou for quick replay ... But even not show any alert of Sub2.mxml  what is the Problem...

Comment: Can you tell me sequence of event flow so that i can figure it out in better way.

Answer (score 2):

Try to create a modelLocator (singleton class and put reference of "editTimetableVO" in that file). This way only a single instance of "editTimetableVO" variable exist in whole application lifecycle, as you have declared this variable as Bindable so changes happen anywhere in application will reflect instantly.

Comment: Not a correct answer to the question: the problem is the Sub1 instance is being created through ActionScript, hence `editDataGrid` is probably `null`. Furthermore, a "ModelLocator" is nothing more than a fancy name for a collection of global variables. There are cleaner ways of passing around variables.

Comment: @RIAstar- ModelLocator is just a name the focus is "Singleton Class" as i described in my answer.