# How to share object between two Popup mxml files in Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, mxml

In my Flex Application have `CreateEvent.mxml` and `AddEvent.mxml` file is their.

In CreateEvent.mxml:

```
[Bindable]public var timetabelVO:TimetableVO = new TimetableVO();//This is external object (java)
-----------
```

Now i want to use `timetableVO` object in AddEvent.mxml file, so i'm doing like this..

```
public var create:CreateEvent = new CreateEvent();
var timetable:TimetableVO = create.timetableVO;
```

But hear `timetable    variable have NULL` value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely it should return null because as your code is saying that you are creating a new object "public var create:CreateEvent = new CreateEvent();" and than trying to initialize a property (var timetable:TimetableVO ) with null instance of a class.

You can find more details at following link - [how to send Java object into between two mxml files in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098540/how-to-send-java-object-into-between-two-mxml-files-in-java/14099066#14099066)